# Why getEnabledProtocols() returns TLS v1 instead of TLSv1.2?

Tags: android, ssl

I came to know from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11337538/1143977) post that JB supports TLSv1.2. Now I am dilemma, when I run the following test code. I get the supported protocol as TLS1.0 and not TLSv1.2. Am doing anything wrong?

```
public class SSLTest extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ssltest);
        SSLSocketFactory mSslSocketFactory = null;
        SSLContext sslContext = null;
        try {
            sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("Default");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        mSslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
        SSLSocket sock = null;
        try {
            sock = (SSLSocket)mSslSocketFactory.createSocket();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[] prots = sock.getEnabledProtocols();
        for(int i=0;i<prots.length;i++){
            Log.d("TEMP","$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ ::: " + prots[i]);
        }
        SSLParameters sslp = sock.getSSLParameters();
        String[] newprots = sslp.getProtocols();
        for(int i=0;i<newprots.length;i++){
            Log.d("TEMP","$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ ::: " + newprots[i]);
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
10-11 11:57:53.280: D/TEMP(7928): $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ ::: SSLv3
10-11 11:57:53.280: D/TEMP(7928): $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ ::: TLSv1
10-11 11:57:53.280: D/TEMP(7928): $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ ::: SSLv3
10-11 11:57:53.280: D/TEMP(7928): $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ ::: TLSv1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're confusing *enabled* and *supported*. The fact that a protocol is supported doesn't mean that it's enabled by default.

If you want to use TLS 1.2, use `setEnabledProtocols` to enable it first, which should work if it's supported in `getSupportedProtocols`.

Comment: Curious that it isn't enabled by default. It's not as though it was insecure, or incompatible.

Comment: Even if i setEnabledProtocols to TLSv1.2 it still does not work. Any ideas what could be the issue. I am getting SSL Handshake aborted error only in the logs.