# Android Client / Server on TLS v1.2

Tags: java, android, ssl

I'm trying my to create TLS v1.2 communication between a server and android client.
I established a TLS v1.0 connection with any problem, but I cannot get v1.2.
This is server code:

```
char[] passphrase = "myComplexPass1".toCharArray();
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keystore.load(new FileInputStream("cacerts"), passphrase);
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
keyManagerFactory.init(keystore, passphrase);
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();
SSLContext sslContext.init(keyManagers, null, null);
SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketFactory = sslContext.getServerSocketFactory();
SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(port);
sslServerSocket.setEnabledProtocols(new String [] { "TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2" });
sslServerSocket.setUseClientMode(false);
sslServerSocket.setWantClientAuth(false);
sslServerSocket.setNeedClientAuth(false);
sslSocket = (SSLSocket)sslServerSocket.accept();
```

while this is client code:

```
char[] passphrase = "myComplexPass1".toCharArray();
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
keystore.load(this.getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.jb), passphrase);
KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyManagerFactory.init(keystore, passphrase);
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
Log.d("Context Protocol",sslContext.getProtocol());//this prints correctly TLS v1.2!
KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();
TrustManager[] trustManagers = new TrustManager[]{
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
                        {
                            return null;
                        }
                        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
                        {

                        }
                        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType)
                        {

                        }
                    }
            };
sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) sslContext.getSocketFactory();
SSLSocket skt = (SSLSocket) sslSocketFactory.createSocket(HOST, PORT);
skt.setKeepAlive(true);
```

Client code, written in a java client running on JRE7 on my pc, perfectly works and I see with getProtocol (server-side) TLSv1.2 with a correct cipher, supported by tlsv1.2.
Same code on android make a tlsv1.0 connection!
I really don't uderstand.
On Java client JRE7 works, on android ONLY tlsv1.0
Any suggestion?

It's my first question, I searched a lot. Probably my formatting is not correct :(

Comment: TLS 1.2 is available on Android 4.1. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950178/implementing-tls-1-2-on-android-2-3-3 for more details.

Comment: Thanks, but according to this [link](http://source.android.com/tech/security/android_4_2_security_enhancements.html) it should be supported. I'm running android 4.2.2

Answer (score 11):

Kind of late to be answering this, but maybe someone else will need an answer.

I have run into the same issue. No matter whether you provide TLSv1.2 to the `SSLContext.init()` method, some Android versions that I've tried do not enable TLS 1.2. You must enable that on your client socket using `setEnabledProtocols()` just as you do for your server socket. For me, I did this in a custom `SSLSocketFactory` I created:

```
public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory
                                throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    private SSLContext mSSLContext;

    public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyManager km) {
        ...
        mSSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        ...
        mSSLContext.init(new KeyManager[] {km}, null, null);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port, boolean autoClose)
                    throws IOException {
        SSLSocket s = (SSLSocket)mSSLContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host, port, autoClose);
        s.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.2"} );
        return s;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: it would be great if you could let me know if this works on Android versions from 2.3 to JellyBean?

Comment: From https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html, TLS 1.2 is only supported for API versions 16+.

Comment: This saved my day. It's weird sometimes the way Android does this kind of stuff, but thanks, a lot.