# "IllegalArgumentException: SSLSocketFactory is null" on some devices, and some not?

Tags: java, android, http, ssl, https

I am using free SSL certificate from StartSSL. I added the PEM encoded certificate to my application.

The implementation works with three of my android phones(all jellybean), but Samsung Galaxy note 1(android version 4.0.4) does not work.

Surprisingly it does not give an SSLException, but a IllegalArgumentException.

Exception more in detail

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: SSLSocketFactory is null
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.java:282)
    at com.lovey.util.NetworkFunction.communicateString(NetworkFunction.java:288)
    at com.lovey.util.NetworkFunction.login(NetworkFunction.java:337)
    at com.lovey.classes.LoginAsync.doInBackground(LoginAsync.java:36)
    at com.lovey.classes.LoginAsync.doInBackground(LoginAsync.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

I think everything is working fine. The input stream that reads certificate in assets is working fine.

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [caused(hyperlink with solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950178/implementing-tls-1-2-on-android-2-3-3) by using TLSv1.2 on android devices with versions lower than Jellybean.

Use this source instead. Also have your server accept TLSv1.0 connections.

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<16)
    sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
else
    sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
```