# Best practice with HTTPS for websites and TLS 1.2

Tags: https

We've recently moved to HTTPS for all requests to our public website and application. We're seeing issues with clients that apparently have TLS 1, 1.1 and/or 1.2 disabled in Internet Explorer (and/or other browsers), the net result being they can no longer access our domain 'at all'.

[image]

Our certificate set up uses TLS 1.2 and I'm forcing HTTP requests in .htaccess to HTTPS. What's the accepted best practice to negate issues with misconfigured browsers? Allow access over HTTP? Allow access but display an error? I'd be interested to know what approaches and techniques people are using to work around this issue.

Given that Google are [encouraging the adoption of HTTPS](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal_6.html) how should we proceed without alienating users that have poorly configured systems?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950178/implementing-tls-1-2-on-android-2-3-3

Comment: This isn't an answer but does offer some insight and guidance. You can use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to check the status of SSL on your domain. :)