# Android <= 4.4.2 and TLS 1.2

Tags: android, ssl, tls1.2

I did an app for a company and it supported API level 13+ (3.0+). It collects data from their CMS via XML and displays it on the app. This is done over HTTPS which worked fine until they upgraded their server to TLS 1.2. Now android versions below API level 20 won't fetch the XML because of `SSLPeerUnverifiedException` and a whole lot of phones can't see this app anymore.

Is there a way to get past `SSLPeerUnverified` while leaving TLS 1.2 enabled?

Note: The current SSL certificates are as follows:

```
AddTrust External CA Root
--> COMODO High-Assurance Secure Server CA
  --> *.appdomain.com
```

Most helpful SOF article so far:
[Implementing TLS 1.2 on Android 2.3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950178/implementing-tls-1-2-on-android-2-3-3)

Comment: no sure but --> TLSv1.2 is supported from api 16+  -- https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html  --  so there should be a solution for the issue -- actually its enabled by default on the server socket for api 16+ but not on the client

Comment: @Tasos You are correct. I'm currently using `HttpClient` and tried setting it's `SocketFactory` to a custom class that enables *TLS 1.2* by default. It hasn't worked yet but it's a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone else on the team answered this but the result included the following:

- `SSLContext helper=null;`
- `helper.init(null,null,null);`
- `SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");`
- `SSLEngine engine = helper.createSSLEngine();`

Here's the function he used to check ssl and put everything in:

```
public void sslCheck() {

        int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST=9000;
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        //Log.i("log_tag2", String.valueOf(resultCode));
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                Log.i("log_tag2","Not good!");
                if (MyAppActivity.instance != null) {
                    Log.i("log_tag2","but can fix");
                    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                            resultCode,
                            MyAppActivity.instance,
                            PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.i("log_tag2","Already good!");
            try {
                ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(this);
                Log.i("log_tag", "1");
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            SSLContext helper=null;
            try {
                helper = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
                Log.i("log_tag","2");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                helper.init(null,null,null);
                Log.i("log_tag", "3");
            } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            SSLEngine engine = helper.createSSLEngine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What happens with `engine`?

Comment: Okay. Thanks i figured everything out. Make sure your Google Play Services are up to date on the device. Use the method Jackson presented and return the SSLContext helper and work with as normal when you use HttpsUrlConnection